# pear php extract soap file attachment using soap_client

Tags: php, soap, get, attachment, pear

I am using PHP pear `Soap_Client` to fetch the mime type data.
The code is

```
$soapclient = new SOAP_Client($url_rec);
$msg = $soapclient->_call('query', $params_rec, $options);
if($msg)
{
    var_dump($soapclient->_soap_transport->attachments);
}
```

if I use `var_dump($msg)` it returns `Soap_fault` error object.
I digged through it  and it gives me parse error in case of file attachment.
If there is no file attachment it is fine.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: It returns Soap_Fault error object

Comment: At least, post the error message.